# Azure AKS static IP Address for aks-istio-ingressgateway-external

Tags: azure, azure-aks, istio

I'm installing istio in azure via

`az aks mesh enable --resource-group 'myrg' --name 'myk8s'`

and then enable the external istio ingress gateways with

`az aks mesh enable-ingress-gateway --resource-group 'myrg' --name 'myk8s' --ingress-gateway-type external`

This all works fine. The last step creates a new public IP and associates the aks-istio-ingressgateway-external service with this IP. But I'd rather provide my own static IP for the ingress. Is there a way to do this via az or terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/mesh?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-mesh-enable-ingress-gateway) at the moment. Not all of the helm parameters you'd normally configure as available `gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerIP` being one of them.

I'd suggest raising the profile of this request with a comment over on the [AKS GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/3649).